# Visual Studio Add-In: How do I know when a solution has finished loading

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, add-in, envdte

I'm writing a VS2008 add-in (using DTE) that needs to be notified after the current solution has finished loading.

I've tried using the following code:

```
events = (Events2) applicationObject.Events
events.SolutionEvents.Opened += DoSomeWorkEvent;
```

Unfortunately it seems that since VS2005 the event is thrown when the solution starts to load - and not when it finishes.

A short internet search produced the [following thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/3fca4a7d-d656-459c-af67-d3a3f71d5a70) that explains the problem and suggest a solution (check each project item to see if it finished loading).

Is this the best solution available or is there a better way to know when a solution has finished loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a workaround that solves this problem - I've created a Windows.Forms.Timer that runs on the main thread and checks if the solution has finished loading.

```
private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       var solution = applicationObject.Solution;
       if (solution.IsOpen && string.IsNullOrEmpty(solution.FileName) == false)
       {
           timer.Stop();
           // insert logic here
       }
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(exception);
   }
}
```